# NestJS cannot resolve dependency of auto-generated files

Tags: nestjs

I have the weirdest problem with my Nest application (living inside Nx, for what it's worth). I've generated a new resource:

```
nx g resource --project testing
✔ Which generator would you like to use? · @nx/nest:resource
✔ What name would you like to use for this resource (plural, e.g., `users`)? · items
✔ What transport layer do you use? · graphql-code-first
✔ Would you like to generate CRUD entry points? (Y/n) · false
```

It was added to `Imports` in the main app.module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      playground: false,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
      autoSchemaFile: "schema.gql",
    }),
    ItemsModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then, I've added simple resolver to have GraphQL happy:

```
// ./items/items.resolver.ts
import { Int, Query, Resolver } from "@nestjs/graphql";

import type { ItemsService } from "./items.service";

@Resolver()
export class ItemsResolver {
  constructor(private readonly service: ItemsService) {}

  @Query(() => [Int])
  getAll() {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  }
}
```

So my items.module looks like that:

```
import { ItemsResolver } from "./items.resolver";
import { ItemsService } from "./items.service";

@Module({
  providers: [ItemsResolver, ItemsService],
})
export class ItemsModule {}
```

which is pretty valid to me. But even though, I am still getting
`Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ItemsResolver (?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the ItemsModule context.`

If I remove the service from the `ItemsResolver` class, all works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `type` from `import type { ItemService }`  inside the `item.resolver` file. The emitted metadata uses a reference to `ItemService`, not just as a type. If you import it as just a type, Typescript will only emit the value as a `Object` and cause the error you see

Comment: ESLint adds it automatically :o Worked like a charm, thanks!